# database not creating and giving error on plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to development so any feedback is appreciated - i have built a wordpress plugin that needs to create a new database table on plugin activation. When I activate the plugin i get the following error, and the new table has not been created.

**'The plugin generated 1050 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.'**

Here's the code:

```
    global $ed_wp_cardealer_db_version;
$ed_wp_cardealer_db_version = '1.0';

//create database table
function create_database(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $ed_wp_cardealer_db_version;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ed_wp_cardealer';
    $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        valuation_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        vrm TINYTEXT,
        price int(9),
        vehicleDescription TINYTEXT,
        email TINYTEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY  (valuation_id)
    )$charset;";
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta( $sql );
    add_option( 'ed_wp_cardealer_db_version', $ed_wp_cardealer_db_version );
}
//create database on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_database' );
```

I've checked it over and over against the wordpress official docs and can't see any obvious errors. If I activate the plugin without this line then there is no error, but the database is still not created

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_database' );
```

I have seen lot's of responses to similar queries that suggest removing extra space from opening php tag etc, but I need to create the new table as well as remove the error.

I have set debug to true in wp-config, but can't see any further details than i have given.

Answer (score 0):

I change valuation_id int value length. When you declare int value in DB must assign int length. Also, add two extra parameters on add_option.

Please try the below code hopefully work it. I test it on my local development server.

```
global $ed_wp_cardealer_db_version;
$ed_wp_cardealer_db_version = '1.0';

//create database table
function create_database(){
    global $wpdb;

    global $ed_wp_cardealer_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ed_wp_cardealer';

    $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = " CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        valuation_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        vrm TINYTEXT,
        price int(9),
        vehicleDescription TINYTEXT,
        email TINYTEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY ( valuation_id )
    )$charset;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php" );

    dbDelta( $sql );

    add_option( 'ed_wp_cardealer_db_version', $ed_wp_cardealer_db_version, '', 'yes' );
}

//create database on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_database' );
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Database create on plugin activation]

Comment: It would help the quality of your answer significantly if you explained what you’ve changed and *why* it’s resolved the errors the OP cites

Comment: @MonzurAlam thank you - I missed the int value but adding the int val and the additional parameters hasn’t fixed my error - I still get the error message and my table is still not created - am I missing something else?

Comment: @martinA, Can you share your full plugin code via Github, dropbox, or onedrive? It's easy to debug your code for me.

Comment: I found a solution, i changed my code and set it like this (found an article on google). I'm not 100% sure why it is so different to wordpress's documentation however this code creates a table on plugin activation without any errors

Comment: //create database on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_database_table' );

Comment: //create database table
function create_database_table(){
    global $wpdb;
    if ($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '" . ed_create_my_table()."'") != ed_create_my_table()){
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `' . ed_create_my_table() .'` (
        `valuation_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `vrm` TINYTEXT,
        `price` int(9),
        `valuation date` TINYTEXT,
        `email` TINYTEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`valuation_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;';

Comment: function ed_create_my_table(){
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prefix . 'ed_wp_cardealer';
}